# the path of images uploaded with laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

I am trying to modify a picture profile in a Laravel project, but when I give the path of picture (avatar) to delete the old picture ; it doesn't work and show me this error:

[image]

this is my view:

```php
<form  method="POST"   action="{{route('UpdateData')}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="row mt-5 text-center ">
        <div class="  main-chat-msg-name">
            <div class=" text-center  avatar avatar-xxl chat-profile mb-3 brround">
            <a class="" href=""><img alt="avatar" src="{{asset('./avatar').Auth::user()->avatar}}"                  class="brround" ></a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

This is my Updatefunction:

```php
public function UpdateData(Request $req)
{
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    // dd($user);

    if ($user) {
        if ($req->has('imgAvatar')) {
            //on supprime l'ancienne image
            $file=$req->imgAvatar;
            // Storage::delete('assets/images/avatar/'.$user->avatar);
            // dd('assets/images/avatar/'.$user->avatar);
            // $image_path = $req->file('imgAvatar')->store('public/assets/images/avatar');
            $image_name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
             //obtenir le nom de l'image à partir du chemin complet
            $file->move(public_path('avatar'),$image_name);
            unlink(public_path('avatar') . '\\' . $user->avatar);
            $user->avatar=$image_name;

        }
    $user->update([
'avatar' => $user->avatar,
        ]);
    }

    return back()->with("message", "Modification faite avec succès");
}
```

public -> avatar :this is the path when the pictures are stored after being uploaded .

please help. thanks

Comment: Please replace the image of the error with text. This will help people understand your answer and other people with the similar issue to find your question.